# Cartesian coordinate / Cartesian plane

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-collection

I designed that Cartesian plane.

```
\documentclass[border=3]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzInit[xmin=-6,ymin=-6,xmax=6,ymax=6]
    \tkzAxeXY
    \tkzGrid
    \coordinate (a) at (2.0,0.0);
    \coordinate (b) at (4.0,3.0);
    \coordinate (c) at (-3.0,-5.0);
    \coordinate (d) at (-4.0,2.0);   
    \draw [color=black,fill=gray,fill opacity=0.5] (a) circle (0.1cm);
    \draw [color=black,fill=gray,fill opacity=0.5] (b) circle (0.1cm);
    \draw [color=black,fill=gray,fill opacity=0.5] (c) circle (0.1cm);
    \draw [color=black,fill=gray,fill opacity=0.5] (d) circle (0.1cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I should make some changes.

How can I add a letter near each point?

How can I increase the thickness of the x and y axis?

I would like to increase the size of the numbers.

I would like to put the + sign for all the positive numbers.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for axes and grid consider this code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[very thin,color=gray!15,step=.5] (-6.1,-6.1) grid (6.5,6.5);
        \draw[-latex] (-6.2,0) -- (6.7,0) node[right] {$x$};
        \draw[-latex] (0,-6.2) -- (0,6.7) node[above] {$y$};
        \coordinate [label=below left:O] (a) at (0,0);
        \foreach \i in {-6,...,-2,-1,1,2,...,6}
        \draw[gray!65] (\i,.1)--(\i,-.1) node[below] {$\i$};
        \foreach \i in {-6,...,-2,-1,1,2,...,6}
        \draw[gray!65] (.1,\i)--(-.1,\i) node[left] {$\i$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**ADD**: If You want add points and labels put (inside the `\tkzpicture` code) this code:

```
\filldraw[black,opacity=.5] (2,0) circle(3pt) node[above] {$A$};
        \filldraw[black,opacity=.5] (4,3) circle(3pt) node[above] {$B$};
        \filldraw[black,opacity=.5] (-3,0) circle(3pt) node[above] {$C$};
        \filldraw[black,opacity=.5] (-4,2) circle(3pt) node[above] {$D$};
```

Answer (score 4):

- add a `label` to the `\coordinate`s, see example below.
- `\tkzAxeXY[very thick]`, for example.
- `\tkzAxeXY[label options={font=\Large}]` for example. (Of course, add that option in addition to `very thick`, see example below.)
- `\tkzAxeXY` uses `\numprint` from the `numprint` package to print numbers, so you can add the `\npaddplus` macro from that package right after `\begin{tikzpicture}`.
- `\tkzAxeXY[orig=false]` to remove zeros, and then add the one zero without plus sign manually, with `\node [below right=3pt,fill=white,font=\Large] {$0$};`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=3]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % \tkzAxeXY uses numprint for number printing
    % this macro turns on explicit plus signs
    \npaddplus

    \tkzInit[xmin=-6,ymin=-6,xmax=6,ymax=6]
    \tkzGrid % moved before \tkzAxeXY
    \tkzAxeXY[
       very thick, % increase width of axes lines
       label options={font=\Large,}, % increase font size 
       orig=false % don't print zeros
    ]
    % add zero label manually
    \node [below right=3pt,fill=white,font=\Large] {$0$};

    % use label=<position>:<text> to add labels next to coordinates
    \coordinate [label=above right:$A$] (a) at (2.0,0.0);
    \coordinate [label=above left:$B$] (b) at (4.0,3.0);
    \coordinate [label=below right:$C$] (c) at (-3.0,-5.0);
    \coordinate [label=below left:$D$] (d) at (-4.0,2.0);   
    \draw [color=black,fill=gray,fill opacity=0.5] (a) circle (0.1cm);
    \draw [color=black,fill=gray,fill opacity=0.5] (b) circle (0.1cm);
    \draw [color=black,fill=gray,fill opacity=0.5] (c) circle (0.1cm);
    \draw [color=black,fill=gray,fill opacity=0.5] (d) circle (0.1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I can't find a way of moving the axis labels, so below is a bit of a hack. Instead of `\tkzAxeXY`, I used `\tkzAxeX` and `\tkzAxeY` separately, as it seems styles can't be set separately. To change both position and font size, I added formatting macros in the `label` setting. So `label=\raisebox{4mm}{\Large$y$}` in `\tkzAxeY` to move the y-label up a bit and increase font size, and similarly `label=\hspace{4mm}\Large$x$` for the x-axis, using `\hspace` to move it right.

[image: output of following code]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % \tkzAxeXY uses numprint for number printing
    % this macro turns on explicit plus signs
    \npaddplus

    \tkzInit[xmin=-6,ymin=-6,xmax=6,ymax=6]
    \tkzGrid % moved before \tkzAxeXY
    \tkzAxeX[
       label=\hspace{4mm}\Large$x$,
       very thick, % increase width of axes lines
       label options={font=\Large}, % increase font size 
       orig=false % don't print zeros
    ]
    \tkzAxeY[
       label=\raisebox{4mm}{\Large$y$},
       very thick, % increase width of axes lines
       label options={font=\Large,}, % increase font size 
       orig=false % don't print zeros
    ]
    % add zero label manually
    \node [below right=3pt,fill=white,font=\Large] {$0$};

    % use label=<position>:<text> to add labels next to coordinates
    \coordinate [label=above right:$A$] (a) at (2.0,0.0);
    \coordinate [label=above left:$B$] (b) at (4.0,3.0);
    \coordinate [label=below right:$C$] (c) at (-3.0,-5.0);
    \coordinate [label=below left:$D$] (d) at (-4.0,2.0);   
    \draw [color=black,fill=gray,fill opacity=0.5] (a) circle (0.1cm);
    \draw [color=black,fill=gray,fill opacity=0.5] (b) circle (0.1cm);
    \draw [color=black,fill=gray,fill opacity=0.5] (c) circle (0.1cm);
    \draw [color=black,fill=gray,fill opacity=0.5] (d) circle (0.1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I would like also the "0" only in the x axis, and also without the "+". Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ryuk See updated code.

Comment: How can I increase the dimensions of the letter "x" and "y" without overlapping with numbers? thanks a lot! ;)

Comment: @ryuk See addition to answer.

Comment: How does one get rid of the short break in the *x*-axis just to the left of the origin?

Comment: @murray By sending a bug report to the package author. It's actually the node for the zero-tick on the y-axis that causes that, it doesn't have any content, but it the `inner sep` means it has some size, and it's filled with white. (Add `fill=red` in the `label options` for  they-axis to see it more clearly.) A better implementation for `orig=false` would be to not add a node for the zero-tick at all. More seriously though, you can cover it up with `\draw [very thick] (0,0) -- (-0.5,0);`, I don't have any better ideas at the moment.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I'm trying to change the size of the letter of every point, but i can't. that's my piece of code:    \coordinate [label=above, font=\Large left:$D$] (d) at (3,0);

Comment: @ryuk To change all the labels, use `\begin{tikzpicture}[every label/.append style={font=\Large}]`. To change a single label, use `\coordinate[label=left:\Large$D$]  (d) at (3,0);`.