# Change two zeros in x and y axes in tikz picture to the letter O

Tags: tkz-euclide

I have been typesetting a mathematics question which requires students to identify the correct point. I want to change the two 0's in the centre of the grid into a letter O slightly to the northwest of the origin. My code and the current output is shown below. Also, please do not change the package to `pgfplots` - I want to let it remain as `tikz`, as there are other diagrams that already look nice with it. Thank you for your help!

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LGRgreek]{mathastext}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tkz-base} % tikz package
\usepackage{tikz} % tikz package
\usepackage{tkz-euclide} % tikz package
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    filecolor=purple,      
    urlcolor=RoyalBlue,
    pdftitle={Math AT1 Year 7},
    pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\showdiv[1]{\overline{\smash{\hstretch{.5}{)}\mkern-3.2mu\hstretch{.5}{)}}#1}}
\let\ph\phantom
\usepackage[a4paper, total={7in, 10.5in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzInit[xmax=5,ymax=5,xmin=-4,ymin=-3]   
   \tkzGrid
   \tkzAxeXY
   \foreach \Point/\PointLabel in {(3,2)/A, (-2,3)/B, (-3,-2)/C, (3,-2)/D}
   \draw[fill=black] \Point circle (0.05) node[above right] {$\PointLabel$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe adapt [tikz pgf - Cartesian coordinate / Cartesian plane - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401909/cartesian-coordinate-cartesian-plane). Just need to change the 0 to O

Comment: @user202729 Hi, may I ask how can I remove the zeros? I have now added the O, but the two zeros are still there

Comment: What about the little horizontal tick for y=0 on the y-axis and what about the little vertical tick for x=0 on the x-axis? Do you want these removed in favor of a diagonal tick going from the origin to the label "O"?

Comment: @UlrichDiez Sorry I didn't specify, I can keep the ticks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `\tkzLabelX` and `\tkzLabelY` have the option `orig` (which skips the `0`), this will still place an empty node at its place that has `fill = white`.

This is why I would first draw the labels and then the axes (that will draw over these white artefacts).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-base,tkz-euclide} % tikz package
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzInit[xmax=5,ymax=5,xmin=-4,ymin=-3]   
   \tkzGrid
   \tkzLabelX[orig]
   \tkzLabelY[orig]
   \tkzDrawX
   \tkzDrawY
   \node[above left] {$O$};
   \foreach \Point/\PointLabel in {(3,2)/A, (-2,3)/B, (-3,-2)/C, (3,-2)/D}
   \draw[fill=black] \Point circle (0.05) node[above right] {$\PointLabel$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Unfortunately, `\tkzAxeXY` also forwards its optional argument to all four `\tkzDrawX`, `\tkzDrawY`, `\tkzLabelX` and `\tkzLabelY` which makes it a bit messy to provide a good style to actually skip the 0 node.

Here `no zero` (when applied to `\tkzAxeXY`) will make a coordinate out of the `0`-node (which hides them completely).

The `make an O` (the letter O, not a zero) style then once again changes the style of the xlabels, reactivates the `rectangle` shape and applies a few settings so that a node with content `$O$` will be added to the north west of the origin.

Since this is a node that is placed along the tick path, I'm using `pos = .5` to get back to the original (could have used `at={(0,0)}` as well). All other keys are there to counteract default settings by Tkz. These can adjusted as you wish, of course. (Better would be to put this into a style like `letter O instead of a zero at the origin` …

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-base,tkz-euclide}
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{
  /tkzlabelX/no zero/.style={
    /tikz/xlabel style/.append style={
      style/.expand once={\ifdim\tkz@pos pt=0pt shape=coordinate\fi}}},
  /tkzlabelY/no zero/.style={
    /tikz/ylabel style/.append style={
      style/.expand once={\ifdim\tkz@pos pt=0pt shape=coordinate\fi}}},
  /tkzAxeXY/no zero/.code=, /tkzdrawX/no zero/.code=, /tkzdrawY/no zero/.code=,
  /tkzlabelX/make an O/.style={
    /tikz/xlabel style/.append style={
      style/.expand once={\ifdim\tkz@pos pt=0pt
        shape=rectangle, fill=none, fill/.code=, % no filling, please
        pos=.5, yshift=+3pt, anchor=south east, % counter default xlabel style
        inner sep=+.3333em, /utils/exec=\def\tkz@Xresult{$O$}\fi}}},
  /tkzAxeXY/make an O/.code=, /tkzlabelY/make an O/.code=,
  /tkzdrawX/make an O/.code=, /tkzdrawY/make an O/.code=}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzInit[xmax=5,ymax=5,xmin=-4,ymin=-3]
   \tkzGrid
   \tkzAxeXY[no zero, make an O]
   \foreach \Point/\PointLabel in {(3,2)/A, (-2,3)/B, (-3,-2)/C, (3,-2)/D}
   \draw[fill=black] \Point circle (0.05) node[above right] {$\PointLabel$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]